# PFInstallation app first launch issue

Tags: parse-platform, launch, relation, pfrelation

i have a serious bug that happens only at first install/launch of my Application.

The situation is this: i have a one-to-many relation on my PFInstallation object and i use the query associated with this relation to get all "user's" objects.
This is working like a charm from the second launch of My App.

During the first launch i have this bug and i can't figure it out how to debug it.

Here's my query code:
EDIT: i've updated this post so you can see the full PFInstallation + PFRelation + PFQuery asynchronous flow.

```
// Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:devToken];
    [currentInstallation setValue:deviceName forKey:@"deviceName"];
    [currentInstallation setValue:deviceModel forKey:@"deviceModel"];

    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    NSString *tzName = timeZone.name;
    NSNumber *secondsFromGMT = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:timeZone.secondsFromGMT];

    [currentInstallation setValue:tzName forKey:@"timeZoneName"];
    [currentInstallation setValue:secondsFromGMT forKey:@"secondsFromGMT"];

    [currentInstallation saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeed, NSError *error){

        NSLog(@"Save installation: %s - error %@",succeed? "YES":"NO",error);

        if (succeed && !error) {

            if ([PFInstallation currentInstallation].objectId != nil){

                PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Event"];

                PFRelation *myEvents = [[PFInstallation currentInstallation]relationForKey:@"events"];

                NSLog(@"Pf installation: %@ \nRelation: %@",[PFInstallation currentInstallation],myEvents.query);

                query = myEvents.query;
                query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;

                [query includeKey:@"Obs"];
                [query includeKey:@"Category"];
                [query orderByDescending:@"DateIni"];

                [query setLimit:100];

                [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
```

as you can see i already have a check if PFInstallation is saved or not...

debugger gets stuck at line:

```
0x1000b0e14:  adrp   x8, #1904640
```

and on thread one is stuck on process [PFQuery markAsRunning]

If i continue the run of my application it does not crash, if i redo the query i got the same error forever and it does not stops.

I kill the application and relaunch... everything works like a charm.

I know it's something like a PFInstallation local save bug, however i get the same PFinstallation log in the first launch of the app and the others.. PFInstallation seems to be saved correctly.

Maybe threading issue?

Anybody has experienced similar bug before?